# Showing doctrine cache stats in symfony web toolbar

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using APCu caching for doctine's query and metadata caches.

I know that one can wrap a cache into a `TraceableAdapter` such that its statistics are shown in the web profiler.

How can I define doctrine's caches to be a TracableAdapter?

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile the doctrine cache package has been deprecated. The recommended way to use a cache is to define a pool, together with an corresponding doctrine adapter service which can then be used in doctrine's config, see below. By that, the pool automatically shows up nicely in the debug tool bar / profiler.

```
framework:
    cache:
        default_redis_provider: 'redis://%env(REDIS_HOST)%/%env(REDIS_DB)%'
        pools: 
            doctrine.metadata_cache_pool:
                adapter: cache.adapter.redis
                default_lifetime: 0
services:
    doctrine.metadata_cache_provider:
        class: Symfony\Component\Cache\DoctrineProvider
        public: false
        arguments:
            - '@doctrine.metadata_cache_pool'
doctrine:
    orm:
        metadata_cache_driver:
            type: service
            id: doctrine.metadata_cache_provider
```